# match first two digit using String.macthes() in place of util Pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have a requirement in which i need to use String.matches with some modification in place of Pattern.compile().matcher().find().
This is for Java code which will be used in GWT project but not on client side.
GWT does not accept `util.regex` as JRE evaluation so had to use String.matches()

Below is the current code which is using `Pattern`. Here requirement is that the number has to start with `1` or `2` or `44`.

```
String s = "1071922746"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[12]|^[4]{2}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.find());  // this will print true.
```

I am trying with below new code.

```
String sNew= s.substring(0,2);
System.out.println(sNew.matches("^[12]|^[4]{2}"); // this will print false.
```

But the new code which is using String.matches will actually compare the entire String with Regex `[12]` or `[4]{2}`.
Is there another way with breaking string we can use matches.

Comment: Group your alternations together and then simply add `.*`, e.g. `^(?:[12]|[4]{2}).*`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, are you aware that you have unused variable `sNew`? Now to the point:

- `Pattern.compile().matcher().find()` - the method [`Matcher::find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) attempts to find the next ***subsequence** of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
- `s.matches("^[12]|^[4]{2}")` - The method [`String::matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) tells whether or not **this string** matches the given regular expression.

Shortly, the first snippet tests whether a substring is present and the second snippet tests the entire String at all. For this reason, you have to match either the rest of the String ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T2SWyO/1)):

```
^([12]|44).*
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that in java (unlike many other languages) the *whole* string must match the regex for [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) to return `true`.

Try this:

```
s.matches("^([12]|44).*");
```

Breaking down the regex:

- `^`: start of input
- `(...|...)`: an *alternation* - like an `OR` of two regexes
- `[12]`: `1` or `2`
- `44` the literal string `"44"`
- `.*` whatever follows